# Volumes of Revolution limits confusion

Tags: integration

> $$f(x) = ln(x+(x^2-1)^{0.5})$$Find the volume generated when the region bounded by the curve $y = f(x)$ and the lines $x = 0$ and $y = 5$ is rotated through an angle of $2π$ radians about the y-axis.

I used the limits 0 and 5, and got a non-real answer error. The answer given uses the limits 1 and 5. Why so?